# Python PIP Fails While Building Docker Image on Windows Server

Tags: python, windows, docker, pip, dockerfile

I have a Windows Server 2016 Box that I am trying to use to build Docker EE Windows containers that deploy a Python Flask application.

I tried building without proxy environment variables and with. I have tried setting proxy environment variables ( I might have done this wrong, I used the Server IP address with the Flask assigned port.)

I have also tried just installing a single package inside of the dockerfile instead of a requirement.txt file without success.

I do not believe the Windows Box has a proxy set because I ran: `netsh winhttp show proxy` and it says `Direct access (no proxy server).`

I tried restarting the docker service and tried building with `--network=host`. I have read it might be worth trying setting the DNS server to 8.8.8.8 but I wasn't exactly sure where to set that up. Can anyone give your experience?

Please keep in mind I can run this with success: `docker run hello-world:nanoserver-sac2016`

Here is the docker file:

```
FROM python:3.8

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .

ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["wsgi.py"]

EXPOSE 8000
```

Here is the error:

```
PS C:\Users\administrator.user1\Desktop\FlaskReportAppDev> docker build -t myflaskapp .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  252.7MB
Step 1/8 : FROM python:3.8
 ---> d070676dfed8
Step 2/8 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f02733df8e5f
Step 3/8 : COPY . .
 ---> ef40674fc745
Step 4/8 : RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
 ---> Running in 6c984bec9495
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000021B39F42F
D0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/click/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000021B39ED33
70>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/click/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000021B3831A2
20>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/click/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000021B39EECA
90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/click/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000021B39F4D4
F0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/click/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement click==7.1.1 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for click==7.1.1
The command 'powershell -Command $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'; pip install -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Comment: It's failing on installing click. Is that the first package in your `requirements.txt`?

Comment: Yes that is correct. I have also tried replacing the pip install requirements line to just pip install <packname>. The pip command just is not wanting to proceed. For example I tried, `pip install click` without success.

Comment: have u got any success?